# how to get specified data from api response (multi array) in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.3

I get stuck along this day , i don;t know how to get specified data from this array or convert this data to an array...

[image: This response from API]

And this my controller :

```
$cari = app('geocoder')->geocode('sukabumi,jawa barat,ID')->get();
    $datas=$cari->formattedAddress;
    return view('cuaca',compact('datas'));
```

my blade.php :

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
<p>{{ $data->formattedAddress }}</p>
@endforeach
```

but it going error massage :

> Cannot access private property
>   Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps\Model\GoogleAddress::$formattedAddress
>   (View: /home/deki/www/ScriptShit/resources/views/cuaca.blade.php)

for example :  how to get only **formattedAddress** value? or **latitude** and **longitude** value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** 
after a few days going research and try a few code now I know how to get specified value from API response .

for example to get only country name :

```
app('geocoder')->geocode('5.43.168.58')->get()->first()->getCountry()->getName();
```

may be someone need this,